# Merge two collections in mongodb without mapReduce…?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have two collections that I want to merge. mapReduce felt a bit overkill so I tried something like this:

```
// setup
use testdb
db.users.remove();
db.profiles.remove();
db.users.save({email: "foo@bar.com", a: "a"});
db.profiles.save({email: "foo@bar.com", b: "b"});

// merge it
db.users.find().forEach(
  function(user) {
    print("updating user " + user.email);
    db.profiles.find({email: user.email}).forEach(function(profile) {
        for(field in profile) {
            if(profile.hasOwnProperty(field) && !(field in user)) {
                db.users.update( {_id: user._id}, { $set : { field : profile[field] } } );
            }
        }
    });
  }
);
db.users.find().pretty();
```

Of course this is broken since "field" is not evaluated but just the json field name. I wanted to do update rather than save though. I suck at js so my question is just: how do I evaluate the field name so I can use it in the json object that $set needs?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok. The [] syntax works of course:

```
db.users.find().forEach(
  function(user) {
    print("updating user " + user.email);
    db.profiles.find({email: user.email}).forEach(function(profile) {
        for(field in profile) {
            if(profile.hasOwnProperty(field) && !(field in user)) {
                var setObj = {};
                setObj[field] = profile[field];
                db.users.update( {_id: user._id}, { $set : setObj } );
            }
        }
    });
  }
);
```